# Oracle Dates to SAS in Passthrough SQL

Tags: oracle, sas

I'm using SAS to connect to an Oracle database, and running into trouble with the dates.  When using pass-through queries, is there a PL/SQL alternative to "DATEPART()" that will save dates as a SAS Date, rather than a SAS Timestamp?  I'd prefer to avoid using LIBNAME or SAS's SQL converter, and would like to do this without an extra SAS data step.

I've experimented with DBSASTYPE= , but it doesn't seem applicable to passthrough SQL.

Example --  "SYS_DATE" from this query is stored as a SAS Timestamp rather than a SAS Date.

```
Proc SQL; 
Create Table WORK.DATE_ORACLE as 
Select * From Connection to ORACLE 
(
SELECT trunc(SYSDATE) as SYS_DATE FROM DUAL
); 
quit ;
```

Comment: You can modify the select * portion, can't you? select datepart(sys_date) from connection to ORacle.....

Comment: Would `cast(SYSDATE as date) as SYS_DATE` work?  (It works for SQL server, I don't have Oracle to test against).

Comment: Casting as date doesn't work -- it's returned as an Oracle date, which includes a time portion.  SAS reads that as a timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Reeza mentions in comments, this is probably easiest done in the non-passthrough section.

```
Proc SQL; 
Create Table WORK.DATE_ORACLE as 
Select datepart(sysdate) as sysdate From Connection to ORACLE 
(
SELECT trunc(SYSDATE) as SYS_DATE FROM DUAL
); 
quit ;
```

If you can't do that, then you're probably best off asking Oracle to turn the date into a text string, bringing it over, and then re-converting it back.

Comment: Thank you for this solution.  It looks like I can't do exactly what I wanted, and this comes closest.